# getting commit of last push/merge in google cloud build

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm using Cloud Build to trigger docker builds whenever someone pushes changes to a branch on cloud source repo. I'm trying to change this behavior to only build the image only when there's a change to the dockerfile.

Doing something like that on github actions would require me to run something like `git diff --name-only ${{ github.event.before }}..${{ github.sha }}` to get a list of files that were changed between the last push/merge and the latest commit, however there doesn't seem to be something equivalent to `{{ github.event.before }}` for cloudbuild. I'd be happy to hear your suggestions on how this can be achieved.

update: it appears using the **included files filter** is a viable solution here

> Included files (optional): Changes affecting at least one of these files will invoke a build. You can use glob strings to specify multiple files with wildcard characters. Acceptable wildcard characters include the characters supported by Go Match, **, and alternation[0].

[0] https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers

Comment: "Something" needs to save the last ending commit, in order to know what to compare with for the diff. Many tools do it for you, and if not, you'll need to automate tracking it yourself.

Comment: It appears that you've answered your own question? If yes, (and if it isn't a dup), consider converting your update into your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears using the **included files filter** is a viable solution here

> Included files (optional): Changes affecting at least one of these files will invoke a build. You can use glob strings to specify multiple files with wildcard characters. Acceptable wildcard characters include the characters supported by Go Match, **, and alternation[0].

[0] https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers